# What is the limit of series?

Tags: sequences-and-series

What is the limit for $ x  \rightarrow \infty $

$ \lim_{x \to \infty}(\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(\frac{x}{n})^{n})^{\frac{1}{x}}?$

Comment: What did you try to solve it ?

Comment: J tried but unsuccessfuly.

Comment: @ProfessorVector Would you kindly explain in details

Comment: Your question was closed as low quality. Please note that there are [site standards](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ). And to be more severe, this is a [one line problem statement question](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), which many users find rude.  Please [edit] your question accordingly.

Answer (score 3):

From the well-known inequality $$\left(1+\frac1k\right)^k<e<\left(1+\frac1k\right)^{k+1},$$
we get $$\frac1{k+1}\,\frac{(k+1)^{k+1}}{k^k}<e<\frac1k\,\frac{(k+1)^{k+1}}{k^k},$$ and multiplying those inequalities for $k=1,\ldots,n,$ we arrive at $$\frac1{(n+1)!}\,(n+1)^{n+1}\le e^n\le\frac1{n!}\,(n+1)^{n+1}$$ (note we have equality for $n=0$). This can be rewritten (with $n$ replaced by $n-1$) $$\frac1{n!}\,n^n\le e^{n-1}\le\frac1{(n-1)!}\,n^n$$ for $n\ge1.$ Thus, we have
$$e\,(e^{x/e}-1)=\sum^\infty_{n=1}\frac{x^n}{n!\,e^{n-1}}\le\sum^\infty_{n=1}\left(\frac{x}{n}\right)^n\le\sum^\infty_{n=1}\frac{x^n}{(n-1)!\,e^{n-1}}=x\,e^{x/e}.$$
So obviously, the limit is $e^{1/e}$.

Comment: very nice solution! but you should provide a link for that "well-known inequality".

Comment: Thank you for all answerings.

Comment: I'll let the mods figure this out, objectively. I'm the first to admit when I make an error.  The error was not offensive; it was a legitimate observation; rather the error was in my trying to put two and two together.  Because of that, I deleted the comment you were seem to be speaking of, and did so before you posted your last comment.  You attacked me personally; I was speaking about your behavior on MSE, not a personal attack.  Fare well!

Comment: @amWhy LOL. the mods are mostly still crazier than you (with one notable exception).

Comment: @amWhy btw, I've got a copy of your original offense, it's not so easy for you to delete that. And I'm ready to provide it, in case anybody is asking. ok?

Comment: @profv  The mods already see it and have already seen my post. Good Day!

Comment: @amWhy Then, we'll just sit back and expect their judgement, won't we?

Comment: @amWhy "non constructive" sums it up nicely, but you do remember who started it? quote:"JCH and ProfessorVector Following a user like you've done repeatedly (to the point where you JCH ping ProfV specifically for help, as you did in a comment below your question) is inappropriate, and the same goes for ProfV following this asker's question; you each upvote each other, and it seems JCH always accepts ProfV's answers. That close and exclusive interaction is a appropriate for a chat room, but not on main.mse. And, I see also "Thank you for all your answerings" directs for you profV."

Answer (score -1):

From Stirling's inequality

$$ \left(\frac{n}{e}\right)^{n}\leq n! \leq ne\left(\frac{n}{e}\right)^{n}$$

$$ \frac{1}{n!}e^{-n} \leq \frac{1}{n^{n}}\leq \frac{1}{(n-1)!}e^{-(n-1)} $$

$$ \frac{x^{n}}{n!}e^{-n} \leq \frac{x^{n}}{n^{n}}\leq \frac{x^{n}}{(n-1)!}e^{-(n-1)} $$

$$ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{x^{n}}{n!}e^{-n} \leq \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{x^{n}}{n^{n}}\leq \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{x^{n}}{(n-1)!}e^{-(n-1)} $$

$$ e^{\large \frac{x}{e}}-1 \leq \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{x^{n}}{n^{n}}\leq xe^{\large\frac{x}{e}}$$

$$ (e^{\large\frac{x}{e}}-1)^{\large\frac{1}{x}} \leq \left(\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{x^{n}}{n^{n}}\right)^{\large\frac{1}{x}}\leq (xe^{\large\frac{x}{e}})^{\large\frac{1}{x}}$$

It follows that

$$ \lim_{x\to \infty} \left( \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(\frac{x}{n}\right)^{n}\right)^{\large\frac{1}{x}} = e^{\large\frac{1}{e}}.$$